# PHP: How to Hide <br /> in Console

Tags: php, console, break

Okay, so I've got a program that converts nl2br, and prints the output to a console window. Though it prints along with the output data, the `<br />`. I'm fine with it and all, if I can't remove/hide it without all the output melding together, but I'd rather hide/remove it if possible. Any suggestions are thankfully accepted.

-Example-
What console says:
 `: Output here!<br />`
What I want:
`: Output here!`

I've tried substr($out, 5), trim(), and that's all I could come up with. All those did was meld the output together.

Comment: I don't understand. Please show us example code and example output. PHP cannot echo things out to console.

Comment: I STILL don't understand. What do you mean by "all the output is melding together".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear, but I suspect you misuderstood nl2br. As the name suggests, it adds for each "newline" a "br" before, so that in HTML (which treats newlines like spaces in text) you will see actualy the text continuing in the next line. When you print to console, the console interprets usually the newline as a newline and so a new line begins. You do not have to use nl2br if you want to output "it" to console. (See [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for details).

Answer (score 1):

That's what `nl2br()` does, changes new line character `\n` to `<br />`.

If you want, take those out, you can use str_replace()

```
str_replace("<br \/>", "", $output);
```